# How to access flags outside of main package?

Tags: go, flags

We [parse flags](http://golang.org/pkg/flag/#FlagSet.Parse) in main.go which is in main package, of course. Then we have another package where we want to read some flag's value.

[flags.Args()](http://golang.org/pkg/flag/#Args) work fine, it will return all non-flag values.

But I cannot figure out to how read already parsed value for a flag in a package other than main.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Amer

Answer (score 17):

I had the same requirement recently and I wanted a solution that avoided calling `flag.Parse` repeatedly in `init` functions.

Perusing the [flag](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/) package I found `Lookup(name string)` which returns a [Flag](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/#Flag) which has a [Value](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/#Value).  Every built in Value implements the `flag.Getter` interface.  The call chain looks like this:

```golang
flag.Lookup("httplog").Value.(flag.Getter).Get().(bool)
```

If you mistype the flag name or use the wrong type you get a runtime error. I wrapped the lookup in a function that I call directly where needed since the lookup and get methods are fast and the function is not called often.  So the main package declares the flag.

```golang
// main.go
package main

import "flag"

var httplog = flag.Bool("httplog", false, "Log every HTTP request and response.")

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    // ...
}
```

And the utility package, which is decoupled from main except for the flag name, reads the flag value.

```golang
// httpdiag.go
package utility

import "flag"

func logging() bool {
    return flag.Lookup("httplog").Value.(flag.Getter).Get().(bool)
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can define the `var` storing the flag in the separate package, as an exported variable, then call the flag parsing in the main package to use that variable, like this:

**mypackage/const.go**

```
var (
    MyExportedVar string
)
```

**mainpackage/main.go**

```
func init() {
    flag.StringVar(&mypackage.MyExportedVar, "flagName", "defaultValue", "usage")

    flag.Parse()
}
```

This way, everybody can access that flag, including that package itself.

**Note**:
 this only works for exported variables.

Comment: This! should be accepted answer. Good that it doesn't introduce flag name dependencies between modules and keeps flag definition and parsing to single module.

Answer (score 6):

You can define the flag in that package and call `flag.Parse()` in `func init()`, `flag.Parse` can be called multiple times.

However, if you want to access the flag's value from multiple packages you have to expose it or create an exposed function to check it.

for example:

```
// pkgA
var A  = flag.Bool("a", false, "why a?")

func init() {
    flag.Parse()
}

// main package
func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    if *pkgA.A {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

Also you can use `FlagSet.Parse(os.Args)` if you want to reparse the args.

Answer (score -2):

When you parse your flags, parse them into global variables which start with an initial Capital so they are public, eg

```
package main

var Species = flag.String("species", "gopher", "the species we are studying")

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
}
```

Then in your other package you can refer to them as

```
package other

import "/path/to/package/main"

func Whatever() {
    fmt.Println(main.Species)
}
```

Comment: I tried this. The problem, is then I get `import cycle not allowed
` That is because other package is under main folder.

Comment: @Amer can't you just pass the args to the other package?

Comment: @OneOfOne, yes we can use that. I really like flags, because it take care of default value and help text in one location. I was hoping the there is an easy way to access flags from outside of main package. But not a big deal if it is not possible. We might just use args and write a custom helper.

Comment: @Amer if the flag is just used by your package you don't need put it in main, or just pass the flag's value from main to the pkg like `pkg.New(flag-value)`.

Comment: Thanks, I know that is a good solution. Probably better than reading global/env value in non-main package. But in our case, main instantiate another class in a different package, that class using factory pattern _may_ instantiate the class where we need to access flags. So this means we will have to pass this value around a bit. This might a bit too much refactoring than worth right now. It looks like `flag.Args()` is the way to go. Thank you @OneOfOne & Nick!